# ORMLite - CallBatchTasks() individually or once for all updates?

Tags: android, ormlite

I'm using ORMLite on Android, and have 7 tables in which I need to create/update multiple entries.

I'm using the `callBatchTasks()` method on each of my dao's individually to do this at present, but I was wondering if it's possible/beneficial to just use one dao's `callBatchTasks()` to process all of the updates?

Would this speed up the process?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Interesting question.  With [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) under Android, all of the DAOs are using the same connection to the same database.  So although it is a little gross looking, you can certainly use a single `fooDao.callBatchTasks()` call to update `Foo`, `Bar`, and `Baz` tables.  That disables the auto-commit on the connection, applies whatever create/update calls you want to which ever tables, and then commits all of the changes at the end.

Comment: Thanks for your help!  A bit of testing has shown there's no difference in performance by doing this, so I'll stick to code that doesn't look gross! :)

Comment: @Gray: Would be helpful to add this information to the documentation. Had them batched separately for quite a while now. And btw: Thanks for giving us ormlite ;-)

Comment: Updating rows on multiple daos with one `callBatchTasks` implementation gives me a SQLException: Getting a writable database from helper failed

Comment: Please post to the ormlite mailing list or another question @JasonRobinson.  Be sure to give the caused by parts of the SQLException.

Comment: I had multiple database instances instead of a singleton all trying to access the same database, so that was my problem. Disregard.